# Packer does not upload or copy files into the userfolder 'C:\Users\<user>'

Tags: windows, packer

I am currently setting up a Windows Server 2019 image with packer. I must copy some config files in the User folder C:\User\user, which is not working. I tried multiple ways:

```
# Copy the files to the image
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "./config/configfile "
    destination = "/tmp/configfile"
  }

# Copy the files to the target path var1
  provisioner "powershell" {
    inline = ["Copy-Item /tmp/configfile -Destination C:/Users/dev_admin/configfile -Force"]
  }

# Copy the files to the target path var2
  provisioner "windows-shell" {
    inline = ["move c:\\tmptmp\\configfile c:\\Users\\dev_admin\\configfile"]
  }
```

I even trieed to copy the file to the /tmp folder and start a PowerShell script to copy the file into the target path. But even this does not work. None of the commands throws an error - they give back a '0'.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Best

Answer (score 0):

Did you login as a admin in to Windows? I had a several problems with packer when i need run some scripts etc. The problem was that in default way any command and scripts are not running with Admin priv. Solution for this was to turn on Autologin on build-in Admin account and run all stuff from this account.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yes, i am using the self generated admin account. Actually the only admin account. All the other installations works propperly. Does packer use another user to execute the provisioner steps?